# Need help in computing inner product matrix for spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was practicing conversion of del operators from Cartesian to Curvillinear coordinates, e.g. spherical coordinates

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x=r sin \theta cos\phi\\ y=rsin\theta sin \phi \\ z=rcos \theta
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I first compute the Jacobian matrix and

$$J^TJ=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\\ 
\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} \\ 
\frac{\partial z}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial r} \\ 
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi} \\ 
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\right)^2 & \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}+ \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}& \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}+ \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}\\ 
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}+ \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} & \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\right)^2 & \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}+ \frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}\\ 
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}+ \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}+ \frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} & \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}\right)^2
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{pmatrix}
sin^2\theta cos^2\phi+ r^2sin^2\theta sin^2\phi+r^2cos^2\theta sin^2\phi& sin^2\theta cos\phi sin\phi - r^2sin^2\theta sin\phi cos\phi + r^2cos^2\theta cos\phi sin\phi& sin\theta cos\theta cos\phi + 0 - r^2cos\theta sin\theta cos\phi\\ 
sin^2\theta cos\phi sin\phi - r^2sin^2\theta sin\phi cos\phi + r^2cos^2\theta cos\phi sin\phi & sin^2\theta sin^2\phi+r^2sin^2\theta cos^2\phi+r^2cos^2\theta sin^2\phi & sin\theta cos\theta sin\phi + 0 - r^2cos\theta sin\theta sin\phi \\ 
sin\theta cos\theta cos\phi + 0 - r^2cos\theta sin\theta cos\phi & sin\theta cos\theta sin\phi + 0 - r^2cos\theta sin\theta sin\phi & cos^2\theta+0+r^2sin^2\theta
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix}
sin^2\theta cos^2\phi+ r^2sin^2\phi& sin^2\theta cos\phi sin\phi - r^2sin^2\theta sin\phi cos\phi + r^2cos^2\theta cos\phi sin\phi& sin\theta cos\theta cos\phi - r^2cos\theta sin\theta cos\phi\\ 
sin^2\theta cos\phi sin\phi - r^2sin^2\theta sin\phi cos\phi + r^2cos^2\theta cos\phi sin\phi & sin^2\theta sin^2\phi+r^2sin^2\theta cos^2\phi+r^2cos^2\theta sin^2\phi & sin\theta cos\theta sin\phi - r^2cos\theta sin\theta sin\phi \\ 
sin\theta cos\theta cos\phi - r^2cos\theta sin\theta cos\phi & sin\theta cos\theta sin\phi - r^2cos\theta sin\theta sin\phi & cos^2\theta+r^2sin^2\theta
\end{pmatrix}$$

But according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47618/definition-of-the-gradient-for-non-cartesian-coordinates?rq=1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923675/difference-between-the-jacobian-matrix-and-the-metric-tensor/956352#956352) link, the inner product matrix G should look like this

$$G=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & r^2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & r^2sin^2\theta
\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore

> Why am I missing some r terms in the Jacobian matrix, thus preventing me from getting the correct G?

Comment: I believe (from your line "$J^T J=\ldots$") that you haven't used the more usual convention for defining the Jacobian, $\frac{D(x,y,z)}{D(r,\phi,\theta)}~$,  but instead its transpose. So your results get mixed up.